# How to give command line args to scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to give command line args to scrapy and use that sys.argv[] in spider to check which urls have that argument. How can I do like this for spider named urls?

$scrapy crawl urls "August 01,2018"?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass arguments to a spider's `__init__()` by using `-a`, as specified in the docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

The default method will make all of the arguments into spider attributes, but you can also create a custom one if you need to do something with them.